# Lightweight laptop with SSD and long battery life

Tags: laptop

I want to buy a new laptop which I'm going to use mainly for watching movies, write latex documents, using mathematica and programming from time to time.

I am interested in a laptop as lightweight as possible with a good battery life. I was thinking in 13" more or less and I have been recommended the [Dell XPS 13](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-13-9350-laptop/pd?ref=PD_OC) but it is much more expensive in Europe than in the USA. Also, I'm going to install Linux in it as soon as I get it so I don't care about the OS.

Is there any similar and cheaper option? The only other requirement that I have is that I want it to have just a SSD.

Comment: Some 11" macbook airs are very very light and small. They can run Windows if you need it

Comment: As @Titus said, just get a cheap laptop (like the ones he mentioned) and replace the HDD - it appears to be a feature that you cannot get for under $1k. An SSD that I recommend (and have in my desktop) is the [Samsung 850 EVO](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820147372)

Comment: By the way, do you have a specific budget?

Answer (score 1):

All the laptops I know that already have an SSD built in are 1000€ and above; so if you want to get below that, you will most probably have to replace the HDD yourself, which will add 60 to 80 Euros to the price for 250GB.
Make sure you get a 7mm drive!

According to [Chip Magazine](http://www.chip.de/artikel/Laptops-mit-gutem-Akku-kaufen-Mobilrechner-mit-langer-Laufzeit_78615676.html), the Acer Aspire E5-571-316T has the best battery for low budget laptops.
It costs around 400€, has about 12 hours of battery working with office, 8.5 hours watching video, but has 15" and weighs 2.3kg. [Video for replacing the HDD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysEMjTPp4hA) (and more)

Acer Aspire ES1-331-C8XF is a just a bit less expensive and also comes with no SSD has "only" 9 hrs/6 hrs of battery, but with 13" it only weighs 1.5kg. [Replacing the HDD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OowstDvLDFY).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Dell's website surfaced with this:

### [New Inspiron 13 5000 Series 2-in-1](http://www.dell.com/ie/business/p/inspiron-13-5368-2-in-1-laptop/pd?oc=bn53602&model_id=inspiron-13-5368-2-in-1-laptop&l=en&s=bsd)

- Price: €689
- CPU: i5-6200U
- RAM: 8GB
- Screen: 13.3 inch 1080p IPS touchscreen
- WiFi: Dual Band AC
- Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4.0
- Ports: Micro SD card reader, 3 USB (2 of which are 3.0), audio jack

It has a **256GB SSD** and it's called "two in one" because it has a 360° hinge on the screen.